# What is a reducible algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In my matrix analysis book, a set of complex matrices is said to be an "algebra" if 1)it is a subspace, 2)whenever A and B are members, so is AB.

Then it uses the terms reducible and irreducible algebra, without defining them. What are the definitions?

EDIT: It's being used within the context of proving Burnside's theorem on matrix algebras... which is written here as... A set S of nxn complex matrices is irreducible if and only if it is the set of all nxn complex matrices.

Comment: It's being used within the context of proving Burnside's theorem on matrix algebras... which is written here as... A set S of nxn complex matrices is irreducible if and only if it is the set of all nxn complex matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algebra of complex $n\times n$ matrices is *reducible* if there is a proper non-zero subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ which is mapped to itself by each element of the algebra. If the algebra is not reducible, it is *irreducible*.