# Given 2 matrices generate a reducible algebra, show they have a common eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Two matrices A, B generate an algebra.... the span of all words made with A and B... example of an element of the algebra: $A^kB^nA^m + I + B^sA^q$ etc... (exponents are all nonnegative). This algebra is given to be reducible. Let W be the nontrivial subspace which this algebra maps to itself.

Please look at Chris' definition of reducible algebra here:
[What is a reducible algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765537/what-is-a-reducible-algebra)

which applies to this question.

How do I show that A and B must have a common eigenvector?

clues I've gathered:
1) I know that W contains an eigenvector of A, as well as an eigenvector of B. But I don't know how to use this to show that there is a common eigenvector.

2) I know there's a matrix S such that $S^{-1}AS$ and $S^{-1}BS$ are both block diagonal of the form: 
$\left( 
\begin{array}{ccc}
Q & R \\
0 & T \\
\end{array} 
\right)$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your definitions of algebra and reducibility, $A$ and $B$ do not neccessarily share a common eigenvector. For instance, consider $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,2,3,4)$ and $B=R\oplus R$, where $R$ is the rotation matrix $\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}$.

Comment: I agree with you. Looks like my book just blundered or missed out some extra conditions.