# A question about matrix algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A,B \in M_n$, $n \geq 2$. If $A$ and $B$ do not share a common eigenvector,  why is $\mathcal{A}(A,B) = M_n$?

Notation and definitions:

$M_n$: the set of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbf{C}^n$

$\mathcal{A}(A,B):$ the algebra generated by $A$ and $B$, defined as the span of the set of all words in $A$ and $B$. A word $W(A,B)$ in $A$ and $B$ is any finite formal product of nonnegative powers of $A$ and $B$:

$$
W(A,B) = A^{m_1}B^{n_1}A^{m_2}B^{n_2}\cdots A^{m_k}B^{n_k}, \quad m_1,n_1,\cdots, m_k,n_k \geq 0
$$

A family $\mathcal{F} \subseteq M_n$ of matrices is reducible if some non-trivial subspace of $\mathbf{C}^n$ is $\mathcal{F}$-invariant.
A subspace $W \subseteq \mathbf{C}^n$ is trivial if $W = \{0\}$ or $W = \mathbf{C}^n$; otherwise it is nontrivial. 
$W$ is $\mathcal{F}$-invariant if $W$ is $A$-invariant for each $A \in \mathcal{F}$.
$W$ is $A$-invariant if $Aw \in W$ for all $w \in W$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766723/given-2-matrices-generate-a-reducible-algebra-show-they-have-a-common-eigenvect?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Burnside's theorem. Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. The algebra generated by $A,B\in M_n(K)$ is whole $M_n(K)$ iff $A,B$ have no common invariant proper subspace. Then, your assertion is false, except if $n=2$.

EDIT. (Answer to Mariano). If $n=2+p\geq 3$, then let  $K^n=E_2\oplus F_p=E_2\oplus G_p$ where $F_p\cap G_p=\{0\}$. Let $A$ be $E_2$ and $F_p$ invariant and let $B$ be $E_2$ and $G_p$ invariant. If $A,B$ have simple eigenvalues and if $A|_{E_2}$ and $B|_{E_2}$ have no common eigenvectors, then $A,B$ have no common eigenvectors and clearly, do not generate whole $M_n(K)$.

Comment: Why is it false?